# Run Javascript faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed, darkmode

I have a toggle that is responsible for changing the color palette of the website as well as some key images. The code works well however I notice that if I visit the site from a computer that I have not used before the key images take a long time to change when the toggle is clicked on.

The main issue is the "sun"/"moon" and "click here" image. I wonder if there is a way to run javascript faster? maybe by changing the positioning of the script or some other trick that I am not aware of. I'll post the website below and all the code, if anyone can point me to some documentation I can read on this or another helpful resource I would very much appreciate it. Love you guys.

Website:
mattmoracoding.com

```js
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 

const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle');

const enableDarkMode = () => {

  document.body.classList.add('darkmode');

  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
  darkModeToggle.src = "Images/sun.png"
  click.src = "Images/click-here-dark.png"
  
  clock1.src = "Images/clock-dark.png"
  clock2.src = "Images/clock-dark.png"
  clock3.src = "Images/clock-dark.png"
  
  currency1.src = "Images/currency-dark.png"
  currency2.src = "Images/currency-dark.png"
  currency3.src = "Images/currency-dark.png"
  
  scrollUp.src = "Images/scroll-dark.png"
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {

  document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');

  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
  darkModeToggle.src = "Images/moon.png"
  click.src = "Images/click-here-light.png"
  
  clock1.src = "Images/clock-light-small.png"
  clock2.src = "Images/clock-light-medium.png"
  clock3.src = "Images/clock-light-large.png"
  
  currency1.src = "Images/currency-light-small.png"  
  currency2.src = "Images/currency-light-medium.png"  
  currency3.src = "Images/currency-light-large.png"
  
  scrollUp.src = "Images/scroll-light.png"
}
 
if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
  enableDarkMode();
}



darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {

  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
  

  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();


  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});


// ---------------------- Scroll Up ----------------------//

const scrollBtn = document.getElementById("scrollUp");

    scrollBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.documentElement.scrollTop= 0;
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Matt Mora Coding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300&family=Playfair+Display:wght@500&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="Scripts/index.js" async></script>

  </head>


  <!--------------------------------------Wrapper------------------------------------>


  <section class="wrapper">


    <!-----------------------------------Navigation---------------------------------->


    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">MM</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a> <a href="Pages/about.html">About</a> <a href="Pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="click-here">
      <img src="Images/click-here-light.png" Id="click" alt="click here">
    </div>

    
    <!--------------------------------Dark/Light Mode-------------------------------->


    <img src="Images/moon.png" id="dark-mode-toggle" class="dark-mode-toggle">
    

    <!-------------------------------------Hero-------------------------------------->


    <div class="hero-title">
      <h1>Hey, I'm Matt Mora</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-body">
      <p>I'm a front end developer.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-social">
      <a  href="https://twitter.com/mattmoracoding">TW</a> <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding">GH</a> <a href="/">LI</a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image-small">
      <img src="Images/me-small.png" alt="Handsome Guy" />
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image-medium">
      <img src="Images/me-medium.png" alt="Handsome Guy" />
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image-large">
      <img src="Images/me-large.png" alt="Handsome Guy" />
    </div>


    <!--------------------------------Section CTA----------------------------------->


    <div class="cta-banner"></div>

    <div class="cta-text-small">
      <p>Checkout my work!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cta-text">
      <p>Checkout some of the things I'm working on!</p>
    </div>


    <!---------------------------------Project1------------------------------------->


    <div class="project1-small">
      <img src="Images/clock-light-small.png" id="clock1" alt="Clock"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project1-medium">
      <img src="Images/clock-light-medium.png" id="clock2" alt="Clock"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project1-large">
      <img src="Images/clock-light-large.png" id="clock3" alt="Clock"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project1-title">
      <h1>Clock</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="project1-body">
      <p>I built this clock as a warm up project to gain experience using HTML and
        more advance css.</p>

      <p>This project taught me how to write more advance CSS and to structure 
        HTML in a simple way.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="languages1">
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Clock-Public/blob/main/Index.html" target="blank"> <img src="Images/html.png" alt="HTML"/></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Clock-Public/blob/main/Style.css" target="blank"> <img src="Images/css.png" alt="CSS"/></a>
    </div>

    <!---------------------------------Project2------------------------------------->


    <div class="project2-small" >
      <img src="Images/currency-light-small.png" alt="Currency Converter" id="currency1"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project2-medium" >
      <img src="Images/currency-light-medium.png" alt="Currency Converter" id="currency2"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project2-large" >
      <img src="Images/currency-light-large.png" alt="Currency Converter" id="currency3"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project2-title">
      <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="project2-body">
      <p>The goal of this project was to expand my understanding of javascript.</p>

      <p>By building this project I learned much more javascript than I had before and allowed me 
        to work on something that I was excited about.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="languages2">
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Currency-Converter-Public/blob/main/Index.html" target="blank"> <img src="Images/html.png" alt="HTML"/></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Currency-Converter-Public/blob/main/Style.css" target="blank"> <img src="Images/css.png" alt="CSS"/></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Currency-Converter-Public/blob/main/Script.js" target="blank"> <img src="Images/java.png" alt="Javascript"/></a>
    </div>

    <!---------------------------------Project3------------------------------------->


    <div class="project3-small">
      <img src="Images/weather-small.png" alt="Weather App"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project3-medium">
      <img src="Images/weather-medium.png" alt="Weather App"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project3-large">
      <img src="Images/weather-large.png" alt="Weather App"/>
    </div>

    <div class="project3-title">
      <h1>Weather App</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="project3-body">
      <p>The goal of this project was to familiarize myself with working with an API.</p>

      <p>I learnt how to use my understanding of HTML, CSS and Javascript to build new 
        project and most importantly I added the ability to work with APIs </p>
    </div>

    <div class="languages3">
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Weather-App-Public/blob/main/Index.html" target="blank"> <img src="Images/html.png" alt="HTML"/></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Weather-App-Public/blob/main/Style.css" target="blank"> <img src="Images/css.png" alt="CSS"/></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/MattMoraCoding/Weather-App-Public/blob/main/Script.js" target="blank"> <img src="Images/java.png" alt="Javascript"/></a>
      <a> <img src="Images/api.png" alt="API"/></a>
    </div>

    
    <!----------------------------------Footer------------------------------------>


    <div class="footer-banner"></div>

    <div class="footer-center">
      <p>Made by Matt Mora</p>
    </div>

    <img src="Images/scroll-light.png" id="scrollUp"/>

  </section>

</html>
```

Comment: You should preload the images so there isn't a lag. There are lots of articles about how to do that in JS.

Comment: I don't think the speed of the Javascript evaluation is a problem here. I suspect the problem to be loading time for your images. Use the developer tools inspector to check how long they need to load. Also check if subsequent toggles are still lagging, if yes, you may need to check the cache headers for your resources

Comment: Didn't notice loading times when changing to darkmode. but preloading is a very good advice. you should also avoid loading images (like `.me-medium` and `.me-small`) and hiding them with css when the screen doesn't meet the requirements (too high or to low resolution). Also have a look on image optimization like `tinypng.com` or `squoosh.app` to reduce image file size

Answer (score 0):

I used your comments to find a resource to preload images only using HTML and CSS. Looks like images are loading faster now without flickering. I will also optimize the images to make them load faster themselves using the sources given but this will take me some time. Let me know what you think of this solution and if there is anything I could do to improve on it.

```css
  #preload { display: none; }
```

```html
    <div id="preload">
        <img src="Images/click-here-light.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Image 01" />
        <img src="Images/click-here-dark.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Image 02" />
        <img src="Images/moon.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Image 03" />
        <img src="Images/sun.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Image 04" />
    </div>
```

`

Comment: This is quite wasteful on bandwidth of clients that never toggle the scheme

Comment: I do notice that even though no flickering occurs now, images do not load as fast as they originally did. Is there a better way to do this? I also optimized every single image on the size using tinypng.com